# WIll maintaining the ratio of 'Voltage/Resistance' violate Ohm's Law?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, electric-current

In an ohmic conductor if voltage and resistance are increased in a constant ratio, the current will remain same and if it remains same, won't it violate the Ohm's Law?
As because Ohm's Law states 'Volate ∝ Current'. And in this case, Voltage is increasing but Current is not.

Comment: Essentially, your question seems to be: If I vary the resistance, will the resistance cease to be constant?

Answer (score 1):

No it won't violate Ohm's law. Because although as you stated, $V \propto I$, it is also true that $V \propto R$, and simultaneously, $I$ is *inversely* proportional to $R$. These three statements are **simultaneously true**. When you increase both $V$ and $R$ at equal rate, then $I$ effectively becomes the proportionality constant.

You can also make an analogy to understand this point further. Let's assume that an object can only ever move at a constant speed. In that scenario, the speed of the object is the proportionality constant between its distance and time (because more time at the same speed covers proportionally more distance). If, on the other hand, you decide to vary speed and distance proportionally, then what you're basically doing is increasing the inherent speed of the object, but also sampling a proportionally further distance (from some set initial position), so the net effect of the experiment is that the observation time is constant. You could thus regard time to be the proportionality constant between distance and speed.

Answer (score 0):

Ohm'law is not actually V ∝ I.
The actual ohm's law states that for ohmic materials, the ratio of the current density J to the Electric field E is a constant $ \sigma$
That is-

$ \frac JE= \sigma $